# python sort list of objects by attribute based on predefined mapping

Tags: python

How can I sort a list of python objects by attribute based on a defined mapping

E.g.

```
import random


class Obj(object):
    attr = None

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.attr

attrs = ['GROUPA', 'GROUPB', 'GROUPC']

objects = []

for x in range(0, 10):
    objects.append(Obj(random.choice(attrs)))

objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda o: o.attr)

print '['
for o in objects:
    print o
print ']'
```

Gives me

```
[
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPC
    GROUPC
]
```

Which is nice, but I would like to define a mapping and take it into account while sorting, for example:

```
mapping = ['GROUPB', 'GROUPA', 'GROUPC']
```

result:

```
[
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPB
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPA
    GROUPC
    GROUPC
]
```

and then get the result like this

Comment: Running your example does not output `[ AAABBBCCC ]` as you write, but `[ GROUPA GROUPA GROUPA GROUPA GROUPA GROUPB GROUPB GROUPB GROUPC GROUPC ]`.  Maybe you should correct the example, or the example output?

Comment: What have you tried? Why not implement [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) on your class?

Answer (score 4):

You can define the mapping in a dictionary with the keys as the characters to be mapped and their values integers with the lower value characters having smaller integers as shown below:

```
mapping = {'B': 1, 'A': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Then you can use this dictionary in your lambda method as:

```
sorted(objects, key=lambda o: mapping[o.attr])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the `cmp` argument of the `sorted` builtin. Define a comparing function where you check whether the elements' corresponding position in the `mapping` list. Something like:

```
def compare(a, b):
    return cmp(mapping.index(a), mapping.index(b))
```

Then, you use it like:

```
objects = sorted(objects, cmp=compare)
```

Even better, as some suggested in the comments, you can bypass the `cmp` argument and directly use `key`:

```
objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda o: mapping.index(o.attr))
```

This way, your code will be compatible with Python 3 and it is much easier to understand.

Comment: `key` is both easier to use and more efficient (it gets called n times, while `cmp` gets called O(n lg n) times): `sorted(objects, key=lambda o: mapping.index(o.attr))`.

Comment: `cmp` is deprecated, not available in Python 3, and the OP is already using the newer `key` argument, a much better option.

Comment: Right, I overcomplicated myself :)